# Ubuntudde says not enough disk space

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I just bought a dell precision 7510 running windows10, and I'm trying to replace it with **ubuntudde**, but the first thing it shows when trying to install it is "not enough space", i tried partitioning the disk but nothing changes .
what should i do next ?

PS:**Ubuntudde** isn't an official flavor of ubuntu that's why I am asking here and not in **askUbuntu**

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your list of partitions as they appear in GParted?

Comment: If you aren't keeping anything.. and you are able to get to a place where you can answer Ramhound's question.. delete everything (aka all partitions) and then run the ***ubuntudde*** setup.